# Hyperledger Fabric: How to deal with node certificate expiry?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

What is the recommendation to deal with an expired peer certificate? Must the network admin periodically update the local MSP of peer with renewed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

MSP identities never expire.

> It is important to note that MSP identities never expire; they can only be revoked by adding them to the appropriate CRLs. Additionally, there is currently no support for enforcing revocation of TLS certificates.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html